# admin gives the number of products printed per row php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, rows, paging

i develop an eshop from scratch, i want when a user choose the category he wants then the products per row he can see its not a static number, for example 3 items per row

i want admin to give for example this : 2;3;4; so thats means : the first row has 2 items, the second 3 items and the third 4 items

how can i manage this?

thats the code i developed :

```
$productsPerRow = 3;
$productsPerPage = 100;
    $sql = "SELECT* from tbl_product order by pd_id desc";
$result     = dbQuery(getPagingQuery($sql, $productsPerPage));
$pagingLink = getPagingLink($sql, $productsPerPage, "c=$catId");
$numProduct = dbNumRows($result);
if ($numProduct > 0 ) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {  
        extract($row);
        if ($pd_thumbnail) {
            $pd_thumbnail = WEB_ROOT . 'images/product/' . $pd_thumbnail;
        } else {
            $pd_thumbnail = WEB_ROOT . 'images/no-image-small.png';
        }   
        if ($i % $productsPerRow == 0) {
            echo '<tr>';
        }               
        ?>  
<Td>
<?php echo $prodname;?>
</td>
if ($i % $productsPerRow == $productsPerRow - 1) {
            echo '</tr>';
        }       
        $i += 1;
    }
```

Comment: wouldn't it be a lot easier to store the number of products in the database, with a link table like product_customer?

Comment: if u mean to store this Number : 2;3;4; in database for sure i stored this Number, the problem is i dont know how to split products per row from this number

Comment: It's a standard database approach.  You have one table that has products, another that has customers, and then a link table like product_customer, with a dual primary key, based off product id and customer id, (or if you have a customer who has more than one transaction, you could just do transaction and product_transaction, instead of customer) and then you could store the number of products on product_customer (or product_transaction) as another key on that table.

Comment: generally it's better to store your data in your database;  and just use php for the interface

Comment: sorry but i think u havent understand me, i have already store products data in database, the problem is i want to server products with a specific sequence, for example if the category i select has 9 products, i want to saw on first row 2 products, on second row 3 products and on last row 4 products, thats the problem i have to solve. it has nothing to do with the admin i said, dont get confused with that, when i say admin i mean someone to give to each category the order that products will appear

Comment: yes, if you have the data stored as I suggested, it's fairly simple, you just run your query (a different one, selecting the data from the product_transaction table with a join off of the other two tables) with a while loop, something  this `while ($row = dbFetchAssoc($result)) {  echo $product_name. ': '. $amount; }`

Comment: in other words, if you structure your data in a more normalized fashion, then querying and echoing the rows becomes much easier

Comment: sorry but u dont help me, you seem not to unserstand whats the problem is

Comment: you might want to read up on sql. You've made your problem much harder than it needs to be.

Comment: its not sql problem, i want to serve data with dynamic way, for example to server in first row 2 products, in second 3 products and go on, thats the point, its php job

Comment: thanks for the help anyway